# Is there a utility to create a multi-Windows bootable USB stick?

Tags: usb, bootloader, bootable-media, disk-utility

After reading [this article](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/01/11/portable-usb-flash-drive-toolkit/) on the SuperUser blog I set out to create a (primarily) Windows boot/install USB, with hopefully a few utilities on it as well (see [my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/220051/35261) for examples).

I've looked at MagicIso, which would look like it would work although it only seems to create a .iso big enough for a dual-layer DVD and as my USB is a 16GB one I'd like to use all the space.

YUMI, while it does offer a Windows Vista/7 boot option it only lists one option for a Windows .iso, one that's been extracted to the USB there's no more options to add a Windows .iso.

What I would like is a USB with a boot menu, that will give me a choice to install, from:

- Windows 7, 32-Bit
- Windows 7, 64-Bit
- Windows Server 2008, 32-Bit
- Windows Server 2008, 64-Bit
- Windows Web Server 2008, 64-Bit

It would be nice if I could also add things like a bootable Ubuntu .iso and a DBAN option, but if not I'll settle for just the Windows option.

Answer (score 1):

[Have you tried XBoot](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/)

[Forum for XBoot](http://reboot.pro/forum/126/)

.

Answer (score 1):

There no such utility.
But there is guide which you can follow.

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/firawiniso

The tutorial is intended for an advanced user.

> This method describes how you can place all your Windows Vista 32-bit/64-bit ISOs, Windows 7 32-bit/64-bit ISOs, Server 2K8 ISOs etc. all on one (large) USB Flash drive and install any version of Windows onto any system whenever you like.